# Sharepoint "Follows me" Colleagues WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I need to create a Sharepoint 2010 "Follows me" WebPart similar to the Colleagues WebPart. I need to see which users has me as a colleague. Is there any way to do it more efficient than looking all users in the site? There are thousands of them...

Comment: I don't get why you want to re-invent something that already exists within SharePoint? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: It is not the Colleagues webpart. I need something to see everyone who has added me as a colleague.

Comment: You can find an answer here:

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18856/is-there-a-who-follows-me-web-part

Comment: You can find the answer here:

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18856/is-there-a-who-follows-me-web-part

Answer (score 0):

this could be the webpart you're looking for...

http://sharepointfacebook.codeplex.com/